# MongoError: $all requires array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am using sailsjs mongodb and node.js
i am getting error following error in mongodb query please help!

i want to get result of those messages which match Exactly with  **$all:  [ senderID , sendToID ]** 
this is my document "message" in mongodb.

```
{
    "users": [
        "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5",
        "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5" 
    ],
    "user_msgs": [],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2014-02-04T11:59:53.220Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2014-02-04T11:59:53.220Z"),
    "_id": ObjectID("52f0d639b922c9142763c336")
}
```

now i want to query

```
    Message.find({ users : {  $all:  [ msg.sender ,   msg.sendTo ]  } })

                    .done(function (err, detail) {
                if (err) {              
                    console.log(err)
                  } else {

                    console.log( detail)}

          });
```

which returns error

```
{[MongoError:$all requires array] name:'MongoError'}
```

i am following  documentation 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/
but still have no idea what is causing problem

Comment: Are `msg.sender` and `msg.sendTo` valid?

Comment: msg.sender and msg.sendTo is a valid value like "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5"

Comment: have you tested your query in the mongo shell to isolate where the problem is coming from? A simple test there also worked for me...

Comment: @chk i am using sailsjs which have a implements [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) and also sails-mongo...

Comment: @AbdulAleem can you test queries directly with the mongo shell nevertheless? Just to check if the query itself works, in that case it would probably be a DB driver issue.

Comment: @chk yes It works fine in mongo shell,I think its sails-mongo driver problem..$all in shall also returns all elements but i need exact match..please tell me how to do Exact matach query i am following [mongodb-chat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671894/how-to-keep-track-of-a-private-messaging-system-using-mongodb) to make my 1-1 and multi user chat server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Waterline there is not a way currently to query embedded records. You can drop down to the native mongo driver in sails-mongo though and run queries. The following should give you what you need.

```
User.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({ users: { 
        $all: [ "52ed09e1d015533c124015d5", "52ed4bc75ece1fb013fed7f5" ] 
    }}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
       // Do something here
    });
});
```